# Calculating number of paid and free products for an x+y offer

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm working on a `x+y` offer feature for a cart system and trying to figure out a way to split a quantity added by the user into paid and free products based on the offer.

Here's the rundown:

```
products in stock: 16
offer: 2 + 1 (every 2 items in cart gets 1 free)
```

#### Example 1

```
items added to cart: 16
paid items: 11
free items: 5
```

#### Example 2

```
items added to cart: 14
paid items: 10
free items: 4
```

#### Example 3

```
items added to cart: 13
paid items: 9
free items: 4
```

#### Example 3

```
items added to cart: 11
paid: 8
free: 3
```

Is there a way to determine these two values through a simple formula?

Comment: I don't understand. Shouldn't the first example have 11 paid items and 5 free?

Comment: I'm sorry, that's right! I fixed my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply round up the fraction of paid items, and round down the number of free items. If $n = x + y$ is the total number of items, we find:

$$x = \left \lceil \frac{2}{3}n \right \rceil, y = \left \lfloor \frac{1}{3}n \right \rfloor$$

As an example, for $n = 16$ we find:

$$x = \left \lceil 10.\overline{6} \right \rceil = 11, y = \left \lfloor 5.\overline{3} \right \rfloor = 5$$

Comment: As an addendum, to generalize this you substitute $2/3$ with $x\over{x+y}$ and $1/3$ with $y\over{x+y}$.

Comment: This works perfectly for each scenario, thanks. Really appreciate it!